# What are the default Schedulers for each observable operator?

Tags: c#, system.reactive

[This page on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh242963%28v=vs.103%29.aspx) states that

> If you do not use the overload which takes a scheduler as an argument, Rx will pick a default scheduler by using the principle of least concurrency. This means that the scheduler which introduces the least amount of concurrency that satisfies the needs of the operator is chosen.  For example, for operators returning an observable with a finite and small number of messages, Rx calls Immediate.  For operators returning a potentially large or infinite number of messages, CurrentThread is called. For operators which use timers, ThreadPool is used.

I would like to actually have a reference sheet for which observable operators use which default Scheduler, but I can't find one anywhere. **What are the default Schedulers for each observable operator?**

Comment: I'm actually surprised there isn't a list somewhere...if I get some time to dump into it, I'll walk through the rx codebase and see if I can compile a list, but no, I'm not aware of any floating 'round the nets...

Comment: Yeah I hunted around too, to no avail. Some of them are obvious but some really aren't!

Answer (score 79, accepted):

Wow, that was not trivial to find...

Deep within the bowels of the `System.Reactive.Concurrency` namespace, there is an internal static class called `SchedulerDefaults`, which is declared as:

```
internal static class SchedulerDefaults
{
    internal static IScheduler AsyncConversions 
    { get { return DefaultScheduler.Instance; }}

    internal static IScheduler ConstantTimeOperations 
    { get { return ImmediateScheduler.Instance; }}

    internal static IScheduler Iteration 
    { get { return CurrentThreadScheduler.Instance; }}

    internal static IScheduler TailRecursion 
    { get { return ImmediateScheduler.Instance; }}

    internal static IScheduler TimeBasedOperations 
    { get { return DefaultScheduler.Instance; }}
}
```

`AsyncConversions` is used by:

```
Start, ToAsync, FromAsyncPattern
```

`ConstantTimeOperations` is used by:

```
Empty, GetSchedulerForCurrentContext, Return, StartWith, Throw
```

`Iteration` is used by:

```
Generate, Range, Repeat, TakeLast, ToObservable, and the ReplaySubject<T>
```

`TailRecursion` is used by:

```
Run
```

`TimeBasedOperations` is used by:

```
Buffer, Delay, DelaySubscription, Generate, Interval, Sample, Skip, SkipLast
SkipUntil, Take, TakeLast, TakeLastBuffer, TakeUntil, Throttle, TimeInterval,
Timeout, Timer, Timestamp, Window
```

Comment: Ideally you would pass in your own scheduler when ever you use any of these method so that you can unit test your code. But it is always good to know which one is the best to use, so this list is great for that!

Comment: @LeeCampbell I was personally astounded at how deep I had to dig to find it...sheesh. Agree 100% on "use your own damned scheduler", tho.

Comment: Thanks. What about `Where` and `Select` and `Do`?

Comment: @ColonelPanic - pretty sure `Where` and `Select` aren't run through any scheduler - not sure about `Do`.

Comment: `Do` certainly isn't either.