# Schedulers in ReactiveUI testing

Tags: c#, unit-testing, system.reactive, reactiveui

So, when I develop new feature for my system, I try too do a TDD - the code is to big to do that for old features right now, sadly.

However, I find that sometimes I hit a brick wall during the tests - especially when using `Delay` and `Throttle`.

I did a lot of reading and I think I know much more than week before, but I wanted to put all of this into pracitce. I wrote some experiments:

```
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Reactive;
    using System.Reactive.Concurrency;
    using System.Reactive.Linq;
    using System.Reactive.Threading.Tasks;
    using System.Text;
    using System.Threading.Tasks;
    using Microsoft.Reactive.Testing;
    using NUnit.Framework;
    using NUnit.Framework.Internal.Commands;
    using ReactiveUI;
    using ReactiveUI.Testing;

    namespace UtilsTests
    {
        [TestFixture]
        public class SchedulersTests
        {
            private int SecondsN = 1;

            [Test]
            public async Task NoScheduler()
            {
                var t = Observable.Return(Unit.Default).Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(SecondsN), RxApp.MainThreadScheduler)
                    .ObserveOn(RxApp.MainThreadScheduler)
                    .ToTask();
                await t;
            }

            [Test]
            public Task ImmediateSchedulerExperiment()
            {
                return Scheduler.Immediate.With(async s =>
                {
                    var t = Observable.Return(Unit.Default).Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(SecondsN), RxApp.MainThreadScheduler).ToTask();
                    await t;
                });
            }

            [Test]
            public Task ImmediateSchedulerExperiment2()
            {
                return Scheduler.Immediate.With(async s =>
                {
                    var t = Observable.Return(Unit.Default).Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(SecondsN), s).FirstAsync().ToTask();
                    await t;
                });
            }

            [Test]
            public void ImmediateSchedulerExperiment3()
            {
                Scheduler.Immediate.With(s =>
                {
                    var t = false;
                    Observable.Return(Unit.Default).Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(SecondsN), s)
                        .Subscribe(_ =>
                        {
                            t = true;
                        });

                    Assert.IsTrue(t);
                });
            }


            [Test]
            public void TestSchedulerExperiment_SchedulersNotSpecified()
            {
                new TestScheduler().With(s =>
                {
                    var t = false;
                    Observable.Return(Unit.Default).Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(SecondsN), s)
                        .Subscribe(_ =>
                        {
                            t = true;
                        });

                    s.AdvanceByMs(SecondsN * 1000);

                    Assert.IsTrue(t);
                });
            }

            [Test]
            public void TestSchedulerExperiment_DeylaOn_RxMainThread()
            {
                new TestScheduler().With(s =>
                {
                    var t = false;
                    Observable.Return(Unit.Default).Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(SecondsN), RxApp.MainThreadScheduler)
                        .Subscribe(_ =>
                        {
                            t = true;
                        });

                    s.AdvanceByMs(SecondsN * 1000);

                    Assert.IsTrue(t);
                });
            }

            [Test]
            public void TestSchedulerExperiment_DeylaOn_RxTaskPool()
            {
                new TestScheduler().With(s =>
                {
                    var t = false;
                    Observable.Return(Unit.Default).Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(SecondsN), RxApp.TaskpoolScheduler)
                        .Subscribe(_ =>
                        {
                            t = true;
                        });

                    s.AdvanceByMs(SecondsN * 1000);

                    Assert.IsTrue(t);
                });
            }

            [Test]
            public void TestSchedulerExperiment_RunOnTaskPool_ObserveOnMainThread()
            {
                new TestScheduler().With(s =>
                {
                    var t = false;
                    Observable.Return(Unit.Default)
                        .Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(SecondsN), RxApp.TaskpoolScheduler)
                        .ObserveOn(RxApp.MainThreadScheduler)
                        .Subscribe(_ =>
                        {
                            t = true;
                        });

                    s.AdvanceByMs(SecondsN * 1000);

                    Assert.IsTrue(t);
                });
            }

            [Test]
            public void TestSchedulerExperiment_RunOnTaskPool_ObserveOnTaskpool()
            {
                new TestScheduler().With(s =>
                {
                    var t = false;
                    Observable.Return(Unit.Default)
                        .Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(SecondsN), RxApp.TaskpoolScheduler)
                        .ObserveOn(RxApp.TaskpoolScheduler)
                        .Subscribe(_ =>
                        {
                            t = true;
                        });

                    s.AdvanceByMs(SecondsN * 1000);
                    s.AdvanceByMs(1);

                    Assert.IsTrue(t);
                });
            }

            [Test]
            public void TestSchedulerExperiment_RunOnTaskPool_ObserveOnMainThread_MainThreadIsAnotherInstance()
            {
                new TestScheduler().With(s =>
                {
                    var mainThreadScheduler = new TestScheduler();
                    RxApp.MainThreadScheduler = mainThreadScheduler;
                    var t = false;
                    Observable.Return(Unit.Default)
                        .Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(SecondsN), RxApp.TaskpoolScheduler)
                        .ObserveOn(RxApp.MainThreadScheduler)
                        .Subscribe(_ =>
                        {
                            t = true;
                        });

                    s.AdvanceByMs(SecondsN * 1000);
                    mainThreadScheduler.AdvanceBy(1);
                    Assert.IsTrue(t);
                });
            }

            [Test]
            public void TestSchedulerExperiment_RunOnTest_ObserveOnTest()
            {
                new TestScheduler().With(s =>
                {
                    var t = false;
                    var obs = Observable.Return(Unit.Default)
                        .Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(SecondsN), s)
                        .ObserveOn(s);
                    obs
                        .Subscribe(_ =>
                        {
                            t = true;
                        });

    //                s.AdvanceByMs(SecondsN * 1000);
    //                s.AdvanceBy(1);

                    s.AdvanceUntil(obs);

                    Assert.IsTrue(t);
                });
            }
        }


    }
```

At first, I thought that `Scheduler.Immediate` will do the trick, executing things after delay right on the spot, and boy, that's wrong. I found [this](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/7f75482f-eff2-4938-9491-47fe870989e8/currentthreadscheduler-vs-immediatescheduler?forum=rx) article, which explained things rather nicely. I found also [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15341864/what-are-the-default-schedulers-for-each-observable-operator) post, explaining which operator uses which scheduler.

I know now, that when playing with time, I should use TestScheduler. Otherwise, don't change the schedulers.

I know now, that you DO NOT do anything async in contructor, instead you create a command called let's say `Init` that does that on activation and you can await it in a test (for example delayd collection creation based on constructor argument to allow smooth UI animations when the view is comples)

BUT, when I run those tests from above, I get that:

[image: Test results]

There are few things I do not understand.

1) Why with `Scheduler.Immediate` the tests take twice the time? I think I get why `Take(1)` does not make difference, but still...

2) When using TestSchduler, how do I determine how much to step forward?

I noticed that in test `TestSchedulerExperiment_RunOnTest_ObserveOnTest` I have to do additional `AdvanceBy(1)`, becuase it's also the observer. So, when the chain is longer, has more observers, it's really hard to count them.

Is it common practice to do `scheduler.AdvanceBy(10000000000000);`?

I tried to create `AdvanceUntil` extension, but I know it sucks for many reasons (cold observables for example).

```
 public static void AdvanceUntil<TIgnore>(this TestScheduler s, IObservable<TIgnore> obs, double? advanceByMs = null)
        {
            var done = false;
            obs.Subscribe(_ => done = true, (ex) => done = true, () => done = true);

            while(!done)
                s.AdvanceByMs(advanceByMs ?? 100);
        }
```

Or maybe there is a "flush" method that I don't know?

Also, I learned to await stuff inside the `TestScheduler.With`:

```
    [Test]
    public Task TestSchedulerExperiment_await()
    {
        return new TestScheduler().With(async s =>
        {
            var v = false;

            var t = Observable.Return(true).Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(SecondsN), s)
                .Take(1) // without hits the test never ends
                .ToTask();
            s.AdvanceByMs(SecondsN * 1000);
            v = await t;

            Assert.IsTrue(v);
        });
```

but I still need to know the time.

And why there has to be `Take(1)`?

Comment: I think `Delay` will also delay `OnCompleted`. So your task without the `Take(1)` will take `SecondsN*2` seconds until it will complete.

Comment: but without specifying the scheduler, it takes 1 second. On screenshot "NoScheduler"

Comment: scheduler.Start() executes everything that has been scheduled, so you don't need that extension method: http://introtorx.com/Content/v1.0.10621.0/16_TestingRx.html#Start

Comment: oh, that's extremely helpful. Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[scheduler.Start()](http://introtorx.com/Content/v1.0.10621.0/16_TestingRx.html#Start) executes everything that has been scheduled, so you don't need that extension method.

I recommend not mixing async/await with Rx most of the time, especially for time-based functionality, which is basically all of your tests because of the Delay operator. Otherwise, you could potentially be waiting minutes for a single test to complete. So async/await serves no purpose in any of them.

For example, in a scenario like your *TestSchedulerExperiment await* test, the test scheduler along with a subscription is all you need. That test would simply become:

```
// Passing test    
[Test]
public void TestSchedulerExperiment()
{
    new TestScheduler().With(s =>
    {
        var v = false;

        Observable
            .Return(true)
            .Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1), s)
            .Subscribe(_ => v = true);

        s.Start();
        Console.WriteLine("Scheduler clock value: {0}", s.Clock);

        Assert.True(v);
    });
}
```

> Why with Scheduler.Immediate the tests take twice the time?

If you really want to delve in and see what's happening under the hood I highly recommend this [Spy extension by James](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20220756/5984310) and add timestamps.

```
var t = Observable
    .Return(Unit.Default).Spy("Return")
    .Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2), RxApp.MainThreadScheduler).Spy("Delay")
    .ToTask();
await t;

// Partial output
Return: OnNext(()) on Thread: 1, 23:22:41.2631845
Delay: OnNext(()) on Thread: 1, 23:22:43.2891836
Return: OnCompleted() on Thread: 1, 23:22:43.2921808
Delay: OnCompleted() on Thread: 1, 23:22:45.2958130
```

*Return* uses ImmediateScheduler and as you may know, RxApp.MainThreadScheduler = ImmediateScheduler in a unit test runner. Because this [scheduler is synchronous](http://introtorx.com/Content/v1.0.10621.0/15_SchedulingAndThreading.html#ImmediateScheduler) Return and Delay notifications both have to wait on each other. Return can't fire its OnCompleted until Delay fires OnNext, and then Delay's OnCompleted notification delays for another 2 seconds.