# Mocking IScheduler for unit testing

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, dependency-injection, rx.net

I'm trying to test rx.net code and I'm totally confused how to go about it. An example from this [website](http://introtorx.com/Content/v1.0.10621.0/16_TestingRx.html) was quite helpful, but I'm unable to connect the final piece. Below is a sample code:

```
class SomeClass 
{

  constructor(IScheduler scheduler)
  {
    var interval = Observable.Interval(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1), scheduler)
      .Take(5);
  }

}

// So in my unit test project I'll inject a TestScheduler as below

public void Test_Some_Class()
{
   var scheduler = new TestScheduler();
   var instance = new SomeClass(scheduler);
   ...
}
```

My question is in my startup file, which implementation of IScheduler should I use:

```
services.AddSingleton<IScheduler, ConcreteImpl>()
```

This stackoverflow [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15341864/what-are-the-default-schedulers-for-each-observable-operator) was quite helpful, but I'm still unable to piece everything together :(

Comment: Does `Scheduler.Default` work?

Comment: Why would you register any startup thingy within the scope of a unit test?

Comment: Sorry but the unit test is in its own project. I've updated the question to reflect that.

Answer (score 1):

You would use AsyncConversions. 
Something like this,

```js
services.AddSingleton<IScheduler, SchedulerDefaults.AsyncConversions>()
```

Answer (score 0):

For some interesting reason, I was got a run-time error yesterday, but everything is working now. Hmm! You can use: `services.AddSingleton<IScheduler>(DefaultScheduler.Instance);` for `TimeBasedOperations` or follow the example [here](http://introtorx.com/Content/v1.0.10621.0/16_TestingRx.html)

```
    public interface ISchedulerDefaults
    {
        IScheduler AsyncConversions { get; }
        IScheduler ConstantTimeOperations { get; }
        IScheduler Iteration { get; }
        IScheduler TailRecursion { get; }
        IScheduler TimeBasedOperations { get; }
    }
```

and reference that instead `services.AddSingleton<ISchedulerDefaults, SchedulerDefaults>();`

For your unit tests you can use:

```
    public sealed class TestSchedulerDefaults : ISchedulerDefaults
    {
        private readonly TestScheduler _timeBasedOperations = new TestScheduler();
        private readonly TestScheduler _asyncConversions = new TestScheduler();
        private readonly  TestScheduler _constantTimeOperations = new TestScheduler();
        private  readonly TestScheduler _iteration = new TestScheduler();
        private  readonly TestScheduler _tailRecursion = new TestScheduler();

        IScheduler ISchedulerDefaults.AsyncConversions => new TestScheduler();
        IScheduler ISchedulerDefaults.ConstantTimeOperations => new TestScheduler();
        IScheduler ISchedulerDefaults.Iteration => new TestScheduler();
        IScheduler ISchedulerDefaults.TailRecursion => new TestScheduler();
        IScheduler ISchedulerDefaults.TimeBasedOperations => _timeBasedOperations;


        public IScheduler AsyncConversions => _asyncConversions;
        public IScheduler ConstantTimeOperations => _constantTimeOperations;
        public IScheduler Iteration => _iteration;
        public IScheduler TailRecursion => _tailRecursion;
        public TestScheduler TimeBasedOperations => _timeBasedOperations;
    }
```

Comment: Isn't it overkill with that many schedulers? [ReactiveUI](https://reactiveui.net/docs/handbook/scheduling/) only has two, because often all you care about is if your tasks run in the background or on the main thread.

Comment: Sure @Magnus, you definitely don't need all. I just provided the full implementation.